# Find where exactly a script is being called from

Tags: shell, solaris

There is a script in a server (known location) that copies a file from one location to another, eg :

```
cp /dirA/file.DAT /dirB/file.DAT
```

This script is being run daily and copies the file, but I don't know what exact process/script is calling it. I looked in crontab but couldn't find anything directly related. What other possible checks could I do ?

OS is solaris

Comment: Rename the script and check for file-not-found-errors in the system messages?

Comment: It could also be an SMF service. I take it you you have attempted to grep recursively for the script name ?

Comment: Dump the environment (`env`) and parent process (`ps -o ppid -p $$`) in the script to some file?

Comment: You 2 options, 1. remove/rename all duplicates except one and try with each for one you are looking. 2. put some debug logic to script to find details.

Comment: Depending on the Solaris version you might consider file audit labeling: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37838_01/html/E61022/flabel-develop.html#scrolltoc. This might give insight in who is accessing the file and might lead into the right direction to the process/mechanism which runs the script.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies/suggestions. I think the most appropriate in my case is to apply @muru suggestion.